# Finding optional lines in multiline text string using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a file that is full of text similar to this one (simplified the lines):

textfile.txt =

```
Domain XXX
    Description AAAA
    Part BBBB
    Id CCCC DDDD
    Next EEEE
```

I need to read the capital letters and stores them as values in dict. This following syntax seems to work.

```
info = re.finditer(r"^(Domain (?P<domain_name>.*)\n)"
    r"( .*\n)*"
    r"( Description (?P<description>.*))\n"
    r"( .*\n)*"
    r"( Part (?P<part>.*))\n"
    r"( .*\n)*"
    r"( Id (?P<id_former>\S+) (?P<id_latter>\S+))\n"
    r"( .*\n)*"
    r"( Next (?P<next>\S+))\n"
    r"",
    textfile,
    re.MULTILINE)
```

This regex syntax works as in I can use it to find the relevant info and call them again using:

```
for i in info:
    result["domain"]=i.group("domain_name")
    result["description"]=i.group("description")
    result["part"]=i.group("part")
    result["id_former"]=i.group("id_former")
    result["id_latter"]=i.group("id_latter")
    result["next"]=i.group("next")

print(result)
{'domain': 'XXX', 'description': 'AAAA', 'part': 'BBBB', 'id_former': 'CCCC', 'id_latter': 'DDDD', 'next': 'EEEE'}
```

My problem is that the **description** line is only optional. My code seems to need to find **ALL** the lines to include them in the dict output and will skip the whole thing if the description is missing.

How can I make the `r"( Description (?P<description>.*))\n"` part of the query return just an empty value if it does not find the description line in the text. Allowing the rest of the attributes to be stored in the dict result variable?

Answer (score 0):

While you probably can do this in Regex, you can also use the `if "Description " in text` check and specify a variable `description = r"( Description (?P<description>.*))\n( .*\n)*"` if True or `description = r""` if False.

The variable `description` can then be inserted with `+ description +` into your `finditer` argument. If you parse multiple blocks with each having an optional `Description` entry, extend it by splitting the blocks from your text file first.